# Dynamically specifying "include" for Entity Framework queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, predicate

I am trying to pass a `List<string>` to a method that will take it and use it to create a list of include statements to be used in an entity framework query.

For example:

```
List<string> myIncludes = new List<string>();
myIncludes.Add("myObject.FirstRelatedObject");
myIncludes.Add("myObject.SecondRelatedObject");
```

I want to use this list to get something like the following, dyamically:

```
var myQry = objectContext.object.Include(myIncludes[0]).Include(myIncludes[1]);
```

How would I go about doing this?  I am using predicateBuilder to generate the "where" part of the statement, but I don't think that's the same thing as the "Include" portion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this (where predicate is your PredicateBuilder):

```
var includes = new List<string>() { "Include1, Include2" };

var query = this.Context.Campos;

foreach(var s in includes)
    query.Include(s);

var result = query.Where(predicate.Expand());
```

Comment: So very right...  I guess I've been so wrapped up in creating predicates, that I didn't see the simple solution right in front of me.  Thanks!